# How to extract/read content from an attached file in abap cds

Tags: file-upload, sapui5, abap, cds

I am creating an abap cloud project with cds that's integrated in btp abap environment on a trial account . I've also managed to upload/attach a csv file from local storage to one of my table fields but when I try to click the file it automatically downloads to local again instead of opening.

How can I open and preview the content of the file after attaching it ?

I tried using the HTTP_GET_URL function but I get an error message saying that the use of the function is not permitted , same with the if_http_client interface